# ¿Como hacer calculos dentro de un datagridview en C#?

Tags: c#, datagrid

Resulta que tengo un datagriedview en la que me aparecen unos datos que puse en su load. Pero lo que quiero yo es hacer calculos de una celda y ponerla en otra.

Por ejemplo[image]

Quiero calcular el valor cuadrado de los valores de la celda xi y cuando de el botón de calcular, que el calculo me aparezca en la celda de xicuadrado

Asi hago para que me aparezcan esos datos:

```
 private void MinimosCuadrados_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add("1", "1", "2", "", "", "");
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add("2", "1.5", "3.2", "", "", "");
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add("3", "2", "4.1", "", "", "");
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add("4", "2.5", "4.4", "", "", "");
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add("5", "3", "5.9", "", "", "");


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que tienes que hacer es un recorrido con un ciclo y aplicar el metodo `Pow()` de la librería `Math` en el evento click de tu botón calcular:

```
        double xi;
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            xi = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["xi"].Value);
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["xicuadrada"].Value = Math.Pow(xi, 2);
        }
```

En la condición se especifica que sea el numero de filas menos uno para que no aplique con la fila vacía del final

Answer (score 1):

Para el calculo usarias la libreria `Math`

[Math.Pow(Double, Double) Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.math.pow?view=netframework-4.8)

Para el calculo podrias iteras las rows del grid

```
foreach(var row in dataGridView1.Rows){

   double xi = double.Parse(row.Cells["xicuadrado"].Value);

   row.Cells["xicuadrado"].Value = Math.Pow(xi, 2).ToString("N2");   

}
```

Es importante darle formato numerico cuando asignas el valor a la celda